# Can't send data with ajax to my php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Can't seem to send data from my html form to a php file which inserts the data into a mysql database.
One of the forms as an example:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="vorID" name="form_vorname" class="form-control" placeholder="Vorname">
    </div>
</div>
```

The ajax script:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#submit_button').on('click', function(e){        
            e.preventDefault(); // preventing default click action
            $.ajax({
                url: 'insert_ma.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: { 
                    vorname:$   ('#vorID').val(),
                    nachname:$  ("#nachid").val(), 
                    plz:$       ("#plzid").val(), 
                    ort:$       ("#ortid").val(), 
                    tel:$       ("#telid").val(), 
                    email:$     ("#emailid").val()
                },
                success: function(output){
                    alert('Erfolgreich');

                }, error: function(output){
                    alert('ajax failed');
                },
            })
        })

    })
</script>
```

And the php file:

```
<?php

//Connection Details
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$hostname = 'localhost';
$databasename = 'plzdb';


$vorname     = ($_post['vorname']);
$nachname    = ($_post['nachname']);
$plz         = ($_post['plz']);
$ort         = ($_post['ort']);
$tel         = ($_post['tel']);
$email       = ($_post['email']);


//Connection-string
$con = mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$databasename);
//$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname,$username,$password,$databasename);

//SQL Query

$sql = "INSERT into plz_person (per_vorname, per_nachname, 
            per_plz, per_Ort, per_tel, per_email, per_bild) 
        VALUES 
        ('$vorname','$nachname','$plz','$ort','$tel','$email','')";



if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

//Close Connection
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

The php file inserts a null row into the databse. I tried for hours now and i got so far, that at least one variable from the html form got passed to the php file.

Hope someone can help me

Comment: Make all of these `$_post` uppercase `$_POST`, it's a [**superglobal**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) and MUST be in uppercase letters. Having checked for errors would have signaled that, which you and many others lately are not doing.

Comment: This looks [terrifyingly insecure](http://bobby-tables.com/). Are you **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php)? When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: This is the first time i am buildiung a webform. How can i check the php for errors? I will sanitize the inputs later, also this is more a proof of concept and it's not going online

Comment: You can either add `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in your script, or make changes to your `php.ini`.  (You don't want to show errors to potential attackers, so it's disabled by default.) I can also recommend installing the extension [XDebug](http://www.xdebug.org) to make the error output more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `$_post` to `$_POST`

For Example

```
$vorname     = $_POST['vorname'];
$nachname    = $_POST['nachname'];
$plz         = $_POST['plz'];
$ort         = $_POST['ort'];
$tel         = $_POST['tel'];
$email       = $_POST['email'];
```

Comment: [`Yeah, I said that`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26493450/cant-send-data-with-ajax-to-my-php#comment41620473_26493450) along with an "explanation". Where's yours?

Comment: Now its only adding the first parameter, the rest is still null

Comment: Change all $_post to $_POST not only first

Comment: Got it! Found a typo at the ids, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The vector $_POST must be uppercase.